# How can I efficiently create a new column in a pandas DataFrame based on another column's rolling mean over a period of 30 days?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, stock

I'm working with a pandas dataframe and working with stock data. I'm trying to create another column based off of another column while trying to avoid the slow for loop. I used a while loop to create a new column of the mean price of the past 30 days because I can't figure out another way...

```
    VOLUME_SERIES = DF.loc[:, 'a_volume']
    VOLUME_SERIES_IND = DF.loc[:, 'a_volume'].index.to_numpy()
    MAX_INDEX = np.max(VOLUME_SERIES_IND)

    period = 30
    period = period - 1
    START = 0
    STOP = START + period

    DF['mean_a_volume'] = np.nan

    while STOP <= MAX_INDEX:
        mean_vol = np.mean(DF.loc[START:STOP, 'a_volume'])
        DF.loc[START, 'mean_a_volume'] = mean_vol
        START = START + 1
        STOP = START + period
```

I actually wish that I could use the .apply() method and np.where() while somehow passing in the index of the row, telling it to not apply anything if the index is greater than MAX_INDEX - period but can't seem to figure out how to get the index of the row in a series...I tried getting the indexes of the series with .apply(lambda x: print(index[x]), it looked ok for the most part but for some indexes it had two indexes so I knew something wasn't quite right and to avoid it...Really stuck here on this and don't know how else to proceed...Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rolling.

```
import pandas as pd
column = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['column'] = column
df['mean'] = df['column'].rolling(2).mean()
```

Comment: Wow it's really that simple! Thank you so much! I really need to take a pandas course...:)

Answer (score 0):

You can use df.rolling method to compute the rolling mean. It is vectorized so it will be a bit more efficient than looping. Here is the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) for it.

Here is the updated code:

```
mean_volume = DF.rolling(window=30).mean()
```